# Firebase get image from URL saved in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I haved saved an image to the Firebase storage and saved its URL into Firebase database,too.

But now,I have another question.How can I get the image back by the URL if my URL saved in firebase database with other text?

Is there any way to do that?

My data saved like this,

[image]

Comment: Can you store url in it's own property in Firebase db?  And then use something like Picasso to render image using the url.

Comment: NO,I didn't try to store url in it's own property in Firebase db.I stored it with string type.So,can url store with its own property?

Comment: Right now there are two questions: "how to find a URL in a string?" and "how to display an image from a Firebase Storage URL on Android?" It's better to tackle such questions one at a time, since the first one has nothing to do with Firebase (and is likely covered in dozens of questions already) and the second one is covered in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui).

Comment: It doesnt make sense to store "This is my picture.\n" string as url prefix. Just store url and follow Frank's answer.

Comment: I thought i know how to do now.thank you.I will try it.

Comment: Highly recommend watching Zero to App (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and checking out it's sample code (https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c).